# DHCP renewal can't go through because DHCP server is down

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, rfc

To my experience, if a DHCP client tries to renew its lease, but the DHCP server is down, and after the lease time is over, there are two possible scenarios:

1. The client keeps the IP
2. The client goes back to INIT state

I've seen the two scenarios before with different vendors.

I can't find exactly which one is according to the standard.
Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Renewal usually happens before expiration - most often starting at 50% lease time.

If the lease eventually expires before a renewal can be DHCPACKed, the client must not continue to use the leased address. It must re-enter the INIT phase from before the lease.

See [RFC 2131](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2131) section 4.4.5 for details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.