# In the event of a DHCP server outage and a lease time of 7 days, how long will a client keep using its assigned address?

Tags: dhcp

There are a lot of questions about DHCP servers/clients/leases, but I haven't found one specifically addressing this.

If I set up a DHCP scope with a lease time of (say) 7 days, and the DHCP server at some point has an extended outage - let's say a month - do all clients just keep using their current lease? Or after some failed attempts to renew, just release the IP address/lease and have nothing?

I'm asking because I'd like to set up DHCP for servers to ease provisioning, and I'm sure someone I work with will ask "but what if the DHCP server goes away in a disaster (or something)?"

Also, assuming the clients are all fine but the DHCP server has to be rebuilt and the lease DB is lost, will the clients re-request their existing IP address and carry on as usual when the new DHCP server comes online? I'm assuming no new clients will appear in the meantime and cause conflicts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DHCP renewal can't go through because DHCP server is down](https://serverfault.com/questions/1136060/dhcp-renewal-cant-go-through-because-dhcp-server-is-down)

Comment: The relevant RFC https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2131 is quite old but for example https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2131#section-4.4.5 seems relevant to address most of your questions

Comment: The required behavior is to continue to renew until the lease expires (seven days), then shut down the network. What do your tests confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do all clients just keep using their current lease?

No

> Or after some failed attempts to renew, just release the IP
> address/lease and have nothing?

Yes

> assuming the clients are all fine but the DHCP server has to be
> rebuilt and the lease DB is lost, will the clients re-request their
> existing IP address and carry on as usual when the new DHCP server
> comes online? I'm assuming no new clients will appear in the meantime
> and cause conflicts.

Clients may attempt to request their previous ip address. To avoid ip address conflicts, your DHCP server should have some type of conflict detection mechanism and it should be enabled.